# Why is setup.cfg's package_dir setting on multiple lines in Python packaging tutorial?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I am following [a tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) on developing Python packages. In this tutorial they show how to setup a basic `setup.cfg` file as follows.

```
[metadata]
name = example-pkg-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE
version = 0.0.1
author = Example Author
author_email = author@example.com
description = A small example package
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject
project_urls =
    Bug Tracker = https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/issues
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License
    Operating System :: OS Independent

[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.6

[options.packages.find]
where = src
```

My question pertains to this part.

```
package_dir =
    = src
```

I don't understand why this is stretched out onto multiple lines. When I replace these two lines with a single line `package_dir = src` I find the following error when I attempt to build.

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsOptionError: Unable to parse option value to dict: src

ERROR Backend subproccess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist
```

What is going on with the apparent necessarity of the multiple lines or assignment operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `= src` is not unindented. It should always look like:

```
[options]
package_dir =
    = src
```

the package_dir maps the packages to their folder, while `= src` is parsed to Python dictionary as `{'': 'src'}`. = src means that `./src` contains all the packages of your distribution

Answer (score 1):

You actually can find more info in the same page

> `package_dir` is a mapping of package names and directories. An empty package name represents the “root package” — the directory in the project that contains all Python source files for the package — so in this case the `src` directory is designated the root package.

`package_dir =` is the configuration param

`= src` means the package name is empty hence

> empty package name represents the “root package”